# Using select case on Power point

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to use vba to insert a textbox and prompt user to type a selection i.e 1-3 and use select case to execute the corresponding code that will change the textbox fill and font color as I have stated.

I'm not too sure what I should put after Select Case, currently I putting Select case y which I think may be the reason my code is not working.

Appreciate if anyone can try to spot my mistake and help me turn it into a working code.

```vb
Sub Insert_Textbox()

Dim sld As slide, sh As Shape, cursh As Shape
Dim y As Long

Dim chtcolor01 As Long, chtcolor02 As Long, chtcolor03 As Long, w As Long, b As Long

w = RGB(250, 250, 250)
b = RGB(0, 0, 0)

chtcolor01 = RGB(250, 0, 0)
chtcolor02 = RGB(0, 250, 0)
chtcolor03 = RGB(0, 0, 250)


Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set sh = sld.shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=150, Height:=50) 'this shape will now be called sh

With sh
y = InputBox("Please select a number between 1 to 3 for the color for your textboxes", "Choose your color!")

Select Case y
Case y = 1

.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = chtcolor01
.textFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = b
.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border

y = 2
.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = chtcolor02
.textFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = b
.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border

y = 3
.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = chtcolor02
.textFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = w
.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border
End With

End Sub
```

The following is the revised code with Steve help. Hope others may find it useful too.

```
Sub Insert_Textbox()

Dim sld As slide, sh As shape, cursh As shape
Dim Y As String

Dim chtcolor01 As Long, chtcolor02 As Long, chtcolor03 As Long, w As Long, b As Long

w = RGB(250, 250, 250)
b = RGB(0, 0, 0)

chtcolor01 = RGB(250, 0, 0)
chtcolor02 = RGB(0, 250, 0)
chtcolor03 = RGB(0, 0, 250)


Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
Set sh = sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=150, Height:=50) 'this shape will now be called sh

With sh
Y = InputBox("Please select a number between 1 to 3 for the color for your textboxes", "Choose your color!")

Select Case Y
Case Is = 1

.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = chtcolor01
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = b
.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border

Case Is = 2
.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = chtcolor02
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = b
.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border

Case Is = 3
.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = chtcolor02
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = w
.Line.Visible = msoFalse 'remove border

Case Else
MsgBox ("The number you typed is invalid, please try again")

End Select

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Case y = 1` you instead can just use `Case 1` (etc)

Comment: InputBox returns a string, not a long so you'll need to either use CLng(InputBox("etc")) or dim Y as a string and later use Select Case Y ... Case is = 1 etc.  And since users are users, ALWAYS include a Case Else so you can apply a default color or show them a message.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your comment. I revised my code with your comment and it works beautifully now. I realize I also missed out an End select to close the select case too.

Comment: @GeraldTow It's a good idea always to hit the compile button before running any code. It won't catch all errors but it'll trap a lot of the "stupid human tricks" ones.